# unable to post message to service worker because controller value is null

Tags: javascript, caching, service-worker

I am trying to make a [website](https://secure-depths-31934.herokuapp.com/) available offline with the help of service workers to cache the files needed by the page.
I am trying to give the user control over which images he wishes to cache.

For this, I am using a function *sendMessage*

```
 function sendMessage(msg){
  navigator.serviceWorker.controller.postMessage(msg);
}
```

where message contains data relative to the image that the user wishes to cache or un-cache.

The service worker contains an event listener for the message event:

```
this.addEventListener('message', function(event){
var data = event.data;
caches.open('v1').then(function(cache){
    if(data.add==1)
        return cache.add(data.url);
    else
        cache.delete(data.url).then(function(response)      
    {
     console.log(response)});
     console.log(event);
    }
 )})
```

The problem I am facing is that the controller is always **null**.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that your service worker is registered, but it isn't active and it isn't controlling your page yet.

If you want your service worker to become active, you can call the function [skipWaiting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerGlobalScope/skipWaiting) in the `install` event handler.

If you want your service worker to control the page as soon as it becomes active, you can use the [Clients.claim](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clients/claim) function in the `activate` event handler.

You can see an example in the [ServiceWorker Cookbook Immediate Claim recipe](https://serviceworke.rs/immediate-claim.html).