# navigator.serviceWorker.controller is null until page refresh

Tags: javascript, service-worker

I work with AngularJS and use service worker to receive push notifications.
But `navigator.serviceWorker.controller` is `null` until page refresh, and I don't know how to solve this problem.

Some code of serviceworker:

```js
self.addEventListener('push', pwServiceWorker.pushReceived);
self.addEventListener('notificationclick', pwServiceWorker.notificationClicked);

// refresh caches
self.addEventListener('activate', function(event) {
    event.waitUntil(
        caches.keys().then(function(cacheNames) {
            return Promise.all(
                cacheNames.map(function(cacheName) {
                    return caches.delete(cacheName);
                })
            );
        })
    );
});
```

And send message to the client in serviceworker when push received:

```js
self.clients.matchAll().then(function(all) {
    console.log(all);
    all.forEach(function(client) {
        client.postMessage(data);
    });
});
```

In mainController.js give message like this:

```js
if (!navigator.serviceWorker || !navigator.serviceWorker.register) {
    console.log("This browser doesn't support service workers");
    return;
}

// Listen to messages from service workers.
navigator.serviceWorker.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
    console.log("Got reply from service worker: " + event.data);
});

// Are we being controlled?
if (navigator.serviceWorker.controller) {
    // Yes, send our controller a message.
    console.log("Sending 'hi' to controller");
    navigator.serviceWorker.controller.postMessage("hi");
} else {
    // No, register a service worker to control pages like us.
    // Note that it won't control this instance of this page, it only takes effect
    // for pages in its scope loaded *after* it's installed.
    navigator.serviceWorker.register("service-worker.js")
        .then(function(registration) {
            console.log("Service worker registered, scope: " + registration.scope);
            console.log("Refresh the page to talk to it.");
            // If we want to, we might do `location.reload();` so that we'd be controlled by it
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            console.log("Service worker registration failed: " + error.message);
        });
}
```

Comment: Post some code otherwise nobody can help you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [unable to post message to service worker because controller value is null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37050383/unable-to-post-message-to-service-worker-because-controller-value-is-null)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

This is expected behavior. To take control over all open pages without waiting for refresh/reopen, you have to add these commands to your Service Worker:

```
self.addEventListener('install', function(event) {
    event.waitUntil(self.skipWaiting()); // Activate worker immediately
});

self.addEventListener('activate', function(event) {
    event.waitUntil(self.clients.claim()); // Become available to all pages
});
```

You can read more about them in [skipWaiting()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerGlobalScope/skipWaiting) docs and [clients.claim()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clients/claim) docs.

Comment: Do these `event.waitUntil(...` functions go in addition to the cache functions (see the original question) or replace them? If replacing them, when do they get used?

Comment: [I found this snippet](https://serviceworke.rs/immediate-claim_service-worker_doc.html) that used them as the callback which worked perfectly for me.

Comment: Another note I want to make is that a [shift+reload will bypass the service worker](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/lifecycle#shift-reload) and the window will be uncontrolled!

Comment: I have these lines in my service worker and navigator.serviceWorker.controller is still null until after a reload of the page. There must be some other thing needed to do as well

Comment: Is there any implication of using `self.skipwaiting()` ?

Comment: @KristiJorgji yes, as stated here https://web.dev/learn/pwa/update#force_override you can have issues with that

Answer (score 4):

Make sure the scope of your service worker includes the url in question.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding and what I've seen, using GitHub repos examples providing a way to update service-worker, on first page load (first install), `navigator.serviceWorker.controller` is always `null`, even with a logic that calls `self.skipWaiting()` or `self.clients.claim()` (I've used a combination of https://whatwebcando.today/articles/handling-service-worker-updates/ and https://github.com/victor-chew/pwa-update if you want to see the full code)

Here's my workaround to avoid that `null` reference

```js
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator)
    {
      // this one may be null on first page load (first SW install)
      if (navigator.serviceWorker.controller)
      {
        // [...] -> do your thing here
      }
      // but this one should be present
      else if ((await navigator.serviceWorker.ready).active)
      {
        // [...] -> do your thing here
      }
      else
      {
        console.warn("Unable to find attached Service Worker !");
      }
    }
```