# ServiceWorker fails on hard reload (Ctrl-Shift-R) in Chrome

Tags: service-worker

Why does service worker fail after a hard reload (Ctrl-Shift-R)?

---- case 1 CHROME --- success

1. Uninstall service worker
2. Load page
3. Page installs service worker
4. Worker.postMessage() succeeds
5. reload page
6. Worker.postMessage() succeeds

---- case 2 CHROME --- failure

1. Uninstall service worker
2. Load page
3. Page installs service worker
4. Worker.postMessage() succeeds
5. **HARD RELOAD (ctrl-shift-R) page** (serviceworker still running according to chrome://serviceworker-internals/ )
6. Worker.postMessage() fails  -- 'error sendingTypeError: Cannot read property 'postMessage' of null'

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When you shift-reload, the reloaded page [will not be controlled by a service worker](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/lifecycle#shift-reload). This is part of the service worker specification.

This just applies for that next page load. Future page loads (that don't involve shift-reload) will continue to be controlled by a service worker, assuming that the page is in scope of one.

Comment: That's a bit of a gotcha for web devs who need to refresh assets frequently

Comment: I think this "feature" has screwed me up for years.  Making matters worse is that the Dev Tools indicate the Service Worker is activated and running!  This explains a lot of the random brokenness.  Thanks so much for your answer!

Answer (score 2):

During development you can use, for example, Chrome's Dev-Tools and set that the service workers are updated on each reload:

[image: Service Worker Upload Settings Chrome Dev-Tools]

For further reference you can read [Googles Web Essentials](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/lifecycle#shift-reload) on this topic.

Comment: Thats helpful, but ultimately I resorted to a page reload if my serviceworker controller was null (which I think is the only option)

Comment: Out of interest, do you check it via `navigator.serviceWorker.controller` or only  `navigator.serviceWorker`?

Comment: I check if navigator.serviceWorker.controller is null -- if so then reload

Comment: Thanks! I do the same but get a usable result only after a manual reload after when the page was initially opened. Do you have any hint?

Comment: Well I think its expected behavior.. Don't do a manual reload, do a location.reload() in javascript if controller is null

Comment: Yes it is intended and expected behaviour - Thanks a lot! I followed the solution of this [solved question at SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38168276/navigator-serviceworker-controller-is-null-until-page-refresh) where the service worker is installed without waiting and made available to all open pages by itself. Works like a charm.