# Reload after hard reload still remains the same

Tags: firebase, vue.js, service-worker, progressive-web-apps, firebase-hosting

I'm studying how to integrating Firebase with Vue.

The features including Realtime database, push notifications and hosting.
I'm using [this PWA template](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/pwa) to do it. It all went out okay until now

### Console Log

**Normal Reload**

```
Notification permission granted.
vendor.6cd80049c4a2849e5a1d.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
app.a0d1f6eb7cc6da4827af.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
(index):1 cZ1T2HZ-...
```

**Hard Reload**

```
Notification permission granted.
index.js:44 current null
(index):1 tokencZ1T2HZ-...
```

Both **current null** & **token** is newly built. It seems that the Firebase Hosting has been caching the old build. When I use hard reload it works perfectly.

Besides that, there's an error of **Unexpected token <** that I have no idea what it is. It works great when I'm using **firebase serve**, but not when I deploy it.

I tried to

- include the Cache-Control in the headers.
- disable cache in network tab of chrome devtools
- unregister service worker(first reload after unregister will work, but after that no)
- hard reload (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>)

I am also aware of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49054293/serviceworker-fails-on-hard-reload-ctrl-shift-r-in-chrome).

Edit: It also works fine in incognito mode(deployed), maybe because of the service worker(firebase-messaging-sw.js) is not running and the notification is disabled.

Comment: Usually a "Unexpected token <" is due to the server returning a 404 html page instead of the file. Check the response content in the Network tab.

Comment: @yuriy636 thanks for your help. The network tab has all status 200. Those 2 files with syntax error seems to be responding the newer version of the build.

Answer (score 0):

My friend told me my website works normal in his browser.
Then I install chromium and open it, it in fact works normally.
Then I realize I haven't go to Devtools > Application > Clear Storage.
I was only clearing cookies, after I click the the **clear site data**, it solves the problem.