# navigator.serviceWorker.controller not available after web worker registration but available after refresh

Tags: javascript, progressive-web-apps, service-worker

`navigator.serviceWorker.controller` is null after I register my webworker:

```
registration = await navigator.serviceWorker.register('/service-worker.js')
console.log(navigator.serviceWorker.controller) <- null
```

Setting a 15s timeout the same behavior occurs.

And `registration.serviceWorker` has the `controller` property still set to `null`.

However, after a soft refresh to the page the controller becomes accessible. why would this be ?

Comment: perhaps it's failing, use try/catch to find out

Comment: I'm unsure what you mean, there's no exception being thrown, the worker is registered correctly (it runs properly thereafter) -- it simply doesn't have the "controller" property until I refresh the page

Comment: This may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38168276/navigator-serviceworker-controller-is-null-until-page-refresh

Comment: That indeed solved the issue, thank you! would it be worth redirecting this question to that in some way or just deleting it ? I think that question in itself is too verbose